# VB.NET / C# read listbox content of another application

Tags: vb.net, process, handler

With my application I want to check what list box entry is selected in another app (different process). Is that somehow possible? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this MSDN article on [ManagedSpy and ManagedSpyLib](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163617.aspx).

Comment: Is there a version for .NET 4.0?

Comment: My guess is, that the same code will compile and run under .NET 4.0 as well.